# complex htaccess redirection for php/yii application

Tags: php, .htaccess, yii, yii-routing

i want this URL: http://m.mysite.com/XYZ12 
to redirect here: http://m.mysite.com/index.php?r=myBook/mobile&oid=XYZ12

Note: XYZ12 will be a dynamic string

Answer (score 0):

in your config.php put something like this:

```
array(
......
'components'=>array(
    ......
    'urlManager'=>array(
        'urlFormat'=>'path',
        'rules'=>array(
            '<oid:\w+>'=>'myBook/mobile',
            ),
        ),
    ),
);
```

It is in the manual too: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/topics.url

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ /index.php?r=myBook/mobile&oid=$1 [R,L]
```

It will redirect /something to /index.php?r=myBook/mobile&oid=something